# Defining log4j logger when name contains spaces

Tags: log4j

I made a mistake defining a logger with a space in it. I was doing

```
Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class + "Foo")
```

instead of

```
Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName() + "Foo")
```

Now the logger is called `"class my.package.MyClassFoo"` and I already deployed it to the productive system. While this is not a critical problem and I'm definitly going to fix this, I'd like to have the output of that logger before our next deployment window.

So here is my acctual question: Can I set up a logger which has a space in the name in the log4j properties? Meaning something like

```
log4j.logger.class my.package.MyClassFoo=DEBUG
```

(which didn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spaces in keys must be escaped with a backslash:

`log4j.logger.class\ my.package.MyClassFoo=DEBUG`

This is not `log4j` specific but standard [Java properties format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties#Format).